# Regex - Delimited IP address match either from start of string or from start of delimiter, also allow wildcard

Tags: regex

I have this regex:

```
(((25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[01]?\d\d?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[01]?\d\d?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[01]?\d\d?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[01]?\d\d?)|\*)(;|;?$))
```

My test string is:
192.168.1.1;192.56.3.23;189.35.2.2;298.23.45.56;192.168.3.24;*;

It works perfectly except for the case of 298.23.45.56 (it matches 98.23.45.45).

Is there a way to start the pattern matching either at the start of the string or after ';'. This way none of the 298.23.45.56 is matched?

Also is there a way the wildcard '*' such that if it exists then none of the IPs are matched? Or is this unconventional use of RegExs?

Comment: What language/tool are you using? From the [regex tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info): "Since regular expressions are not fully standardized, all questions with this tag should also include a tag specifying the applicable programming language or tool."

Comment: How about [this](https://regex101.com/r/BY5Z4N/1)

Comment: @Toto that's exactly why I asked the question. With my current Regex it was showing as 2 not being matched rather than the full 298.23.45.56 not being matched

Comment: @Toto the one you showed shows several semicolons as not being matched. So my system flags it as incorrectly constructed string.

Comment: [updated](https://regex101.com/r/BY5Z4N/2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
(?:^|\;)(((25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[01]?\d\d?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[01]?\d\d?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[01]?\d\d?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[01]?\d\d?)|\*))
```

I changed it to match something that starts with either nothing (beginning of the string) or a semicolon, followed by the IP.
https://regex101.com/r/Q6comb/1

EDIT: as for the second part of your question, it might be possible, but I wouldn't recommend it